# bcp sql server 2014 - amazon

Tags: sql, import, bcp

I'm trying to use BCP command in a SQLCMD, but i have some problems, one of them:

I'm trying to import a file from server to another (Amazon to Another Server) and I Followed this

PROMPT> bcp dbname.schema_name.table_name in C:\table_name.txt -n -S endpoint,port -U master_user_name -P master_user_password -b 10000

but returns the following error:
Mensagem 102, Nível 15, Estado 1, Servidor AMAZONA-U1FHTV5, Linha 1
Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reading the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx (available in different languages).

Try also looking at some bcp usage examples at google.

I'm not sure if I'm right, but I think the problem here is your statement syntax